# Create a member for the UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to do some research but couldn't figure it out, so is it possible to create a member for the class UIViewController, or any class for that matter?

In every single one of my UIViewController subclasses I declare the data member

```
userdata = [NSManagedObject]()
```

So I was wondering if I could declare the variable "userdata" inside the actual UIViewController class, either directly or through an external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a sub-class of `UIViewController` which has the `userdata` property and then derive all of your view controllers from that class instead of `UIViewController`

Something like:

```
class BaseViewController:UIViewContrller {
    var userdata = [NSManagedObject]()
}

class NewViewController:BaseViewController {
    // Your sub view controller implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: Ha! Can't believe I didn't think of this. Perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use extensions.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var userData : [NSManagedObject] {
        get {
            return [NSManagedObject]()
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want every `UIViewController` to have that property, you will have to use subclassing.

```
class DataViewController:UIViewContrller {
    var userdata = [NSManagedObject]()
}

class NewViewController:DataViewController {
    // Do something stuff to the View here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extensions if `userData` is a computed property:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var userData: [NSManagedObject] {
        get { return an array from somewhere else }
        set { set the value to somewhere else }
    }
}
```

If your property is not computed but stored, you must use a subclass:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var userData: [NSManagedObject] = []
}
```

And make every VC of yours inherit this class. The disadvantage of using this approach is that your view controllers can't inherit any other class, like `UITableViewController`.

So here is the best method I came up with.

Create a protocol:

```
protocol MyVC {
    var userData: [NSManagedObject] { get set }
}
```

Now make every VC of yours conform to this protocol. In every VC, just start typing `userData` and use enter to select the right completion that Xcode provides and the property will be automatically added for you. If you forgot to do this, the compilation will fail.